# From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to another process listening inside the same container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have spent a couple of hours researching this and the consensus seems to be that using `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` should allow one process within a container to connect to another process within the same container.

However, `host.docker.internal` does not work for me.

Environment:

- Docker Desktop 4.6.1 running on Windows 10
- `docker run` command running on WSL2 Ubuntu

Command:

- `docker run -p 80:80`

Error

- Connection timeout

`Dockerfile` contents

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
COPY xxx/target/AAA.jar AAA.jar
COPY xxx/target/BBB.jar BBB.jar
COPY xxx/target/CCC.jar CCC.jar
COPY ./dockerboot.sh dockerboot.sh 
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./dockerboot.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
```

`dockerboot.sh` contents

```
java -jar AAA.jar &
java -jar BBB.jar &
java -jar CCC.jar &
wait
```

The `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC` jars contain java Springboot applications listening on ports 80, 8081, and 8082 respectively.

Comment: Connecting to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` works for me if I'm trying to connect within a single container. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, that just gives me a `Connection refused`

Comment: Is there a race condition inside your container? If you run those three jars, is it possible for one of them to connect before another process starts listening for connections?

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm watching the logs and waiting until all three are up and running before I send a request. Is your environment the same as mine? I have a suspicion that this is a Windows/WSL2 specific issue.

Comment: `host.docker.internal` will connect you to the host i.e. the machine that's running the Docker engine not to the localhost of the same container. `host.docker.internal` and `localhost` cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: `I don't think so, because I'm watching the logs and waiting until all three are up and running before I send a request.` How are you sending the request from within the container?

Comment: The request comes into the webapp on port 80 from outside the container (e.g. using `curl` from the CLI). The webapp then invokes local microservices on ports 8081 and 8082 and this is where it fails when running inside the container.

Comment: Unrelated issue might be root cause .... `no main manifest attribute` on one of the jars

Comment: Why not run this in three containers, and use normal Docker container networking (neither `localhost` nor `host.docker.internal`)?  (With this setup, if one of the services fails to start up as in your last comment, you won't notice, and you can't restart one of the services to fix it without restarting all three.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

It turns out the root cause of my issue was unrelated to Docker networking:

One of the microservice jars was malformed (`no main manifest attribute`) and was not starting up correctly, hence, failing to listen on port 8081 and causing `Connection refused`.